# Pylons 0.9.6 Get Current Server Name

Tags: python, pylons, paster

In my Pylons config file, I have:

```
[server:main1]
port = 9090
...config here...

[server:main2]
port = 9091
...config here...
```

Which are ran using:

```
paster serve --server-name=main1 ...(more stuff)...
paster serve --server-name=main2 ...(more stuff)...
```

Now, using Haproxy and Stunnel, I have all http requests going to main1 and all https requests going to main2. I would like some of my controllers to react a little differently based on if they are being requested under http or https but pylons.request.scheme always thinks that it is under http even when it is not.

Seeing as I always know that main2 is always the one handling  all https requests, is there a way for the controller to determine what sever name it was ran under or what id it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by just changing the workflow to not have to react differently based on what protocol it's under. It doesn't look like there's a way to pass a unique arbitrary identifier to each separate process that it can read.